# How to get encoding=utf-8 to appear an a WCF xml response?

Tags: wcf, utf-8

How can I ensure the root element of a WCF response is preceded with the XML declaration including the encoding="UTF-8" attribute?

It seems the default response is utf-8 but that does not appear in the header.  I'm looking for my response document to start with this header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: You better fix your parser instead of adding fields that aren't required in order to satisfy it. If that is the problem, of course.

Comment: The open311 api spec requires it...maybe it's okay to ignore that part.

Answer (score 1):

The default encoding (`TextMessageEncodingBindingElement`) does not emit the XML Declaration for UTF-8 encoding. So you need to use a different encoding for that. The "[Custom Message Encoder: Custom Text Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx)" sample should give you full control over the XML writer, including the writer settings which you can use to force the XML declaration to be output.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. The default XML writer used by WCF does not emit the XML declaration for UTF-8 encoding. And to change the XML writer one needs to use a custom encoder. And to use a custom encoder one needs to define both an encoder factory and an encoding binding element... WCF is extensible, but conciseness isn't really one of its strengths...